# Three.js - Width of view

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a way to find out the width of a rendered portion of the scene?

For example, if we have a mesh of width 100, but rendered with a certain level of zoom...how can I calculate the width of the portion of the mesh that is being rendered in the screen?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You have to be precise here.

You can calculate the visible rectangular region given the camera's field-of-view, `camera.fov`, and a given distance, `dist`, from the camera.

Since the object presumably has depth, you have to pick one plane through the mesh, and do the calculation at that distance.

Here is how to calculate the visible `height` and `width` for a given distance `dist` from the camera.

```js
const vFOV = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad( camera.fov ); // convert vertical fov to radians

const height = 2 * Math.tan( vFOV / 2 ) * dist; // visible height
    
const width = height * camera.aspect;           // visible width
```

EDIT: There is now a built-in method available: `PerspectiveCamera.getViewSize()`:

```js
const target = new THREE.Vector2(); // create once and reuse it

camera.getViewSize( distance, target ); // result written to target
```

three.js r162

Comment: Is `dist` a value from FAR value of camera properties?

Comment: `dist` must be less than `FAR`, otherwise the location will not be visible.

Comment: trully... I misunderstood, from what does `dist` occur.. Can't see the previous definition of it value in code, describe please, what is the `dist`? Dtis = Far - Near or not? Thanks!

Comment: `dist` is the distance from the camera. If you need help, please make a new post. Thank you.

Comment: I have done one question, but it's rather just have a little common with this question, maybe you can help? Here is a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606513/not-raycasting-but-custom-geometry-casting-in-three-js-intersection thank you!

Comment: You can use `camera.aspect` instead of calculating `aspect` yourself. And, for the sake readability, you can compute `vFOV` by doing `THREE.Math.degToRad(camera.fov)`.

Comment: @XåpplI'-I0llwlg'I- Thanks. Updated answer.

Comment: THREE.Math is now THREE.MathUtils

Comment: @Mike Thanks! Updated.

Comment: usually, camera.position.z is dist.

Answer (score 0):

For a (perfect) spherical object, it will cover more of the view close up as you need to take the tangent into account i.e. you can't see the 'poles'.

Use the following for a spherical object:

```
// we're using the following triangle: camera - tangent point on sphere - centre of sphere
var targetAngle = 2 * Math.asin(objectRadius / distanceToCamera);

var vFOV = THREE.Math.degToRad(this.fov);

var normalizedHeight = targetAngle / vFOV;
```

Multiply this with your viewport width to get screen height. For width you need to apply hFOV - see: [90 degree field of view without distortion in THREE.PerspectiveCamera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655930/90-degree-field-of-view-without-distortion-in-three-perspectivecamera)