# THREE.JS: Get object size with respect to camera and object position on screen

Tags: three.js

I am newbie to 3D programming, I did started to explore the 3D world from WebGL with Three.JS.

I want to predetermine object size while I change the camera.position.z and object's "Z" position.

For example:
i have a cube mesh at size of **100x100x100.**

```
cube = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 100, 100, 1,1,1, materials),     
        new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial()
    );
```

and cam  with aspect ratio of **1.8311874**

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, aspect_ratio, 1, 30000 );
```

I want to know size (2D width & height) of that cube object on screen when,

```
camera.position.z = 750;
cube.position.z = 500;
```

Is there is any way to find it/predetermine it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can compute the visible height for a given distance from the camera using the formulas explained in [Three.js - Width of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350875/three-js-width-of-view/13351534#13351534).

```
var vFOV = camera.fov * Math.PI / 180;        // convert vertical fov to radians
var height = 2 * Math.tan( vFOV / 2 ) * dist; // visible height
```

In your case the camera FOV is 45 degrees, so

```
vFOV = PI/4.
```

(Note: in three.js the camera field-of-view FOV is the *vertical* one, not the horizontal one.)

The distance from the camera to the *front face* (important!) of the cube is 750 - 500 - 50 = 200. Therefore, the visible height in your case is

```
height = 2 * tan( PI/8 ) * 200 = 165.69.
```

Since the front face of the cube is 100 x 100, the fraction of the visible height represented by the cube is

```
fraction = 100 / 165.69 = 0.60.
```

So if you know the canvas height in pixels, then the height of the cube in pixels is 0.60 times that value.

The link I provided shows how to compute the visible width, so you can do that calculation in a similar fashion if you need it.

Comment: Is there a way to get the visible width and height of a cube when using orthographic camera?