# Three.js zoom to fit width of objects (ignoring height)

Tags: three.js

I have a set of block objects, and I'd like to set the perspective camera so that their entire width is fully visible (the height will be too big - that's OK, we're going to pan up and down).

I've seen there are a number of questions close to this, such as:

[Adjusting camera for visible Three.js shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274358/adjusting-camera-for-visible-three-js-shape)

[Three.js - Width of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350875/three-js-width-of-view)

[THREE.JS: Get object size with respect to camera and object position on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331358/three-js-get-object-size-with-respect-to-camera-and-object-position-on-screen)

[How to Fit Camera to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614252/how-to-fit-camera-to-object)

[ThreeJS. How to implement ZoomALL and make sure a given box fills the canvas area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761644/threejs-how-to-implement-zoomall-and-make-sure-a-given-box-fills-the-canvas-are)

However, none of them seem to quite cover everything I'm looking for:

- I'm not interested in the height, only the width (they won't be the same - the size will be dynamic but I can presume the height will be larger than the width)
- The camera.position.z (or the FOV I guess) is the unknown, so I'm trying to get the equations round the right way to solve that

(I'm not great with 3D maths. Thanks in advance!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to simplify this problem a lot, in my case...

Since I knew the overall size of the objects, I was able to simply come up with a suitable distance through changing the camera's z position a few times and seeing what looked best.

My real problem was that the same z position gave different widths, relative to the screen width, on different sized screens - due to the different aspect ratios.

So all I did was divide my distance value by camera.aspect. Now the blocks take up the same proportion of the screen's width on all screen sizes :-)

Comment: Seeing the downvotes (with no comments)... Should I delete this Q&A then? When I go to do that, it tells me "We do not recommend deleting questions with answers... Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking". So it seems like a choice between two bad options now... :-/

Comment: Could you please provide a technical solution. A code snippet or whatever. Otherwise this really does not help anyone coming up with the same question.

Comment: @MichaelCzechowski I tried to delete the question, but it says "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it..." :(

Comment: You've missunderstood me. Hey, your question is worthy to leave it on SO. Just adjust your question and answer. That's fine. I had to tackle the same issue.

Comment: Even some years later someone has the same issue and is disappointed that there is no code to copy ;-)

Comment: @poshaughnessy What do you mean by "... divide my distance value by..." what was your "distance"? is it the `Z` of the camera position?