# Transforming normals from worldspace to the viewspace

Tags: opengl, graphics

Let's say I have my normals in worldspace and I want to transform them into viewspace. What should I do? I have already tried to multiply them by viewProjection matrix and by inversed transformed view matrix, but both didn't work. Blue channel (z axis) appears to be missing. I am confused.
[image]

Comment: How do you visualize your normals? If you just do somehting like `out_color.rgb=normal`, all the negative components of your normal will be clamped to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **on fixed pipeline do nothing it does the work for you**

   to work properly all world/object transforms should be inside modelview matrix else some advanced things like **FOG** will not work properly (ie `GL_PROJECTION` matrix abuse) but in most cases you do not see a thing ...
2. **on shaders you can handle lighting your self so this is the way**

   ```
   point'  = object_2_world_matrix * world_2_camera_matrix * projection_matrix * point
   vector' = object_2_world_matrix(with origin 0,0,0) * world_2_camera_matrix(with origin 0,0,0) * vector
   ```

   `object_2_world_matrix` is transformation matrix representing rendered model space

   `world_2_camera_matrix` is inverted transformation matrix representing camera space

   Z axis is usually view direction

   `projection_matrix` is just perspective matrix (used for rendering ...)

   you can make any matrix with origin `(0,0,0)` by setting its `12,13,14` element to zero  (elements are `0,..,15`)

You did not remove matrix positions which transforms normal vectors to position of vertex ... That is the reason for weirdness ... so either substract the offset of matrices from the result or multiply by matrices without offset (`origin = (0,0,0)`)

Comment: Your matrix multiplications are in reverse or transposed. Usual notation in computer graphics is vectors are column, and matrix multiplication is right-to-left (matrix multiplication is non-commutative).

Comment: oh you are right ... my mistake (I am a bit ill so i miss it) ... it shoud be reverse (as I use it too) I will edit it in while ... thx for pointing it out the element 12,13,14 stays as is  (in that previous case it would be 4,8,12)