# ThreeJS update Camera position so Plane world position matches DIV screen position

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

### Goal

I want to update the *Camera Position* so that a *Plane World Position* matches a DIV *Screen Position*.

[image: before update]
[image: after update]
[image: different perspective]

### First thoughts

I need to calculate `camera.position.z` - so that the planes face matches the size of the `DIV` - **even when resizing the canvas.**

```
this.computeZ = function(meshHandle, cameraHandle, faceHeight, targetHeight){
    var face = meshHandle.geometry.vertices[2]
    var vFOV = cameraHandle.fov * Math.PI / 180;  
    var vHeightPartial = 2 * Math.tan( vFOV / 2 );
    var p1 = faceHeight * window.innerHeight;
    var p2 = face.z * vHeightPartial;
    var p3 = targetHeight * vHeightPartial;
    var p4 = targetHeight * p2;
    var p5 = p1 + p4;
    var z = p5/p3;
    return z;
}
```

[See `computeZ` in action here.](http://jsfiddle.net/gigablox/m91c44tj/)

### Next steps

The world face size now matches the `DIV` screen pixel size.

Next we need to find a `camera.position.x` and `camera.position.y` - so that the face directly overlaps the `DIV`.

**I've studied...**
[How to Fit Camera to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614252/how-to-fit-camera-to-object/14614736#14614736)
[Three.js - Width of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350875/three-js-width-of-view)
[THREE.JS: Get object size with respect to camera and object position on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331358/three-js-get-object-size-with-respect-to-camera-and-object-position-on-screen)
[Converting World coordinates to Screen coordinates in Three.js using Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586527/converting-world-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates-in-three-js-using-projection)

*...But have been struggling to build something that works for `computeX` and `computeY`*

### Please help

Take a look at the `computeX` and `computeY` functions in [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gigablox/m91c44tj/) I've provided. *These functions are my best attempt - but do not work.*

**How do I build these functions?**

### Update

I've come up with a [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/gigablox/gryeejyj/) with the help of [Craig's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43753829/1113921). This class builds on his methods to cover resize events.

Comment: Checkout this article, it might help you: http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/30/closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/

Comment: The math used here might be helpful too https://github.com/mikatalk/webgla-meetup-three-intro/blob/master/src/js/steps/02/Step02.js#L38-L42

Comment: @mika That math is exactly what's needed. Elegant one-liner, as opposed to some complicated function. Worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>SO code</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/85/three.min.js"></script>
    <style>
          html,body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
  }
  #content{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
  }
  #box{
    position:absolute;
    background:orange;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    bottom:100px;
    right:100px;
  }
    </style>
    </head>
 <body>
 <div id="content">
   <div id="box"></div>
 </div>
<script>
 function Terrain(){

   this.container = document.getElementById('content');
   this.camera;
   this.scene; 
   this.renderer;
   this.light;

   this.computeZ = function(meshHandle, cameraHandle, faceHeight, targetHeight){
    var face = meshHandle.geometry.vertices[2]
   var vFOV = cameraHandle.fov * Math.PI / 180;  
   var vHeightPartial = 2 * Math.tan( vFOV / 2 );
   var p1 = faceHeight * window.innerHeight;
   var p2 = face.z * vHeightPartial;
   var p3 = targetHeight * vHeightPartial;
   var p4 = targetHeight * p2;
   var p5 = p1 + p4;
   var z = p5/p3;
      
   //calculate dom element center coordinate
   var screenPositionX = 0;
   var screenPositionY = 0;
   var div = document.getElementById('box');
   var divDim = div.getBoundingClientRect();
   screenPositionX = (divDim.left + divDim.right) / 2;
   screenPositionY = (divDim.bottom + divDim.top) / 2;
   var vector = new THREE.Vector3((screenPositionX / window.innerWidth) * 2 -1, (screenPositionY / window.innerHeight) * 2 -1, 0.5);
    //unproject camera
   vector = vector.unproject(this.camera);
   var distanceZ = this.camera.position.z - vector.z ;
   var offsetX = vector.x * (z-10) / distanceZ;
   var offsetY = vector.y * (z-10) / distanceZ;
   var cameraPosition = new THREE.Vector3(offsetX,offsetY,z);
   return cameraPosition;
  }
   
  this.computeX = function(meshHandle, cameraHandle, faceHeight, targetWidth){
    var div = document.getElementById('box');
   var divDim = div.getBoundingClientRect();
   var y =  ((divDim.left + (targetWidth/2)) / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
   return y;
   }
   
   this.computeY = function(meshHandle, cameraHandle, faceHeight, targetHeight){
   var div = document.getElementById('box');
   var divDim = div.getBoundingClientRect();
   var y =  ((divDim.top + (targetHeight/2)) / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
   return y;
   }
   this.onDocumentClick = function(event)
   {
      var vector = new THREE.Vector3(( event.clientX / (window.innerWidth) ) * 2 - 1, -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
                vector = vector.unproject(this.camera);

                console.log(vector);
   }
   this.init();
 }

 Terrain.prototype.init = function () {

  this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
  this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

  this.geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20);
  this.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
  this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material );
  this.scene.add( this.mesh );
  
  var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x00ff00, 0.5 );
  this.scene.add( ambient );

  this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, alpha: true } );
  this.renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement );
   
  window.animations['terrain'] = this.animate.bind(this);
  window.addEventListener( 'resize', this.onWindowResize.bind(this), false );
  document.addEventListener('click',this.onDocumentClick.bind(this), false);
 }

 Terrain.prototype.onWindowResize = function(){
  this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
   this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
   this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 }

 Terrain.prototype.animate = function(){
    //this.camera.position.x = this.computeX(this.mesh, this.camera, 20, 100);
   //this.camera.position.y = this.computeY(this.mesh, this.camera, 20, 100);
   this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );
 }

 function animate(){
   for(var i in window.animations){
     window.animations[i]();
   };
   window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 }

 window.animations = {};
 var terrain = new Terrain();
 window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 var newPosition = terrain.computeZ(terrain.mesh,terrain.camera,20,100);
 terrain.camera.position.x -= newPosition.x;
 terrain.camera.position.y += newPosition.y;
 terrain.camera.position.z += newPosition.z;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

To solve the problem, I flow these two steps, 1: get the dom element coordinate in 3D space. 2: using similar triangles calculate offset of x and y. I will show you how to use similar triangles.

[image]

Cause the camera is a perspective camera. now the dom element, the camera and the mesh can make a triangle, if we ignore the Y dimension, the triangle would look like this picture.

Now, we know dom element coordinate in 3D space, and you got the right 'z', we also know the green cube's depth. and we need to calculate the offset x(purple line in the picture). It's obviously that these triangles in the picture are similar triangles. `vector.x / offsetX = vector.z / z - mesh.geometry.parameters.depth`. and we can do the same thing to get the `offsetY`.

Comment: Thank you for putting so much time and effort into this explanation. I was able to build on your solution for resize events. Feel free to consult  http://jsfiddle.net/gigablox/gryeejyj/ for reference :) When bounty becomes available, I'll reward you for your efforts.

Comment: @DanKanze Thank you, your question is very interesting.

Comment: An alternative solution with a fixed camera position to move objects within the scene rather then the camera. http://jsfiddle.net/gigablox/e28eotue/4/