# height and width of View region in three js

Tags: three.js

I have positioned my camera at a distance of 850 (camera.position.z = 850) and camera.setlens(50) and perspective FOV as 70. How can I calculate width and height of View (I just want to draw cube so I want the width and height of View which changes from camera distance.)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350875/three-js-width-of-view/

Comment: var vFOV = camera.fov * Math.PI / 180;        // convert vertical fov to radians
var height = 2 * Math.tan( vFOV / 2 ) * dist; // visible height

var aspect = window.width / window.height;
var width = height * aspect; 

I know this calculation but I just want to know how dist is calculated with respect to camera.setlens will this change anything. 
is below calculation correct in my case.
var vFOV = 70 * Math.PI / 180;        
var height = 2 * Math.tan(vFOV / 2) * 850;

var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
var width = height * aspect;
will setlens involves in the calculation.

Comment: As aspect ratio is same, I want to know screen width and height with respect to camera position so that I can draw a cube dynamically with respect to height and width of screen which is changed with respect to camera.