# Load a 3d Object from obj file and fit it inside the camera using Three.Js

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, perspectivecamera, frustum

I am trying to load(dynamically) object files using THREE.OBJLoader and place them in the center of a scene(or canvas), so that the whole object can be visible in the Camera. Objects are dynamic, so I don't have fixed height or width data.

**What I have got:**
[image]

**What I want:**
[image]

**What I have referred to get to this point:**

1. [Three.js zoom to fit width of objects (ignoring height)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462848/three-js-zoom-to-fit-width-of-objects-ignoring-height)
2. [How to Fit Camera to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614252/how-to-fit-camera-to-object)
3. [Smart Centering and Scaling after Model Import in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766163/smart-centering-and-scaling-after-model-import-in-three-js)
4. [Adjusting camera for visible Three.js shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274358/adjusting-camera-for-visible-three-js-shape)
5. [Calculate camera zoom required for object to fit in screen height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059612/calculate-camera-zoom-required-for-object-to-fit-in-screen-height)
6. [Move camera to fit 3D scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866350/move-camera-to-fit-3d-scene)
7. [Three.js calculate object distance required to fill screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589915/three-js-calculate-object-distance-required-to-fill-screen)
8. [How to calculate the z-distance of a camera to view an image at 100% of its original scale in a 3D space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533135/how-to-calculate-the-z-distance-of-a-camera-to-view-an-image-at-100-of-its-orig)

**Code:**

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);

controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
controls.zoomSpeed = 5;
controls.panSpeed = 2;
controls.noZoom = false;
controls.noPan = false;
controls.staticMoving = true;
controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

// scene
scene = new THREE.Scene();

var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setBaseUrl(path);
mtlLoader.setPath(path);
mtlLoader.setMaterialOptions({
    ignoreZeroRGBs: true
});

mtlLoader.load(path, function(materials) {
    materials.preload();
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
    objLoader.setPath(path);
    objLoader.load(path, function(object) {

        var helperBox = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper(object, 0x888888);
        helperBox.update();
        scene.add(helperBox);

        //Scene
        scene.add(object);

        var boxFrmScene = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(scene);
        var height = Math.max(boxFrmScene.size().y, boxFrmScene.size().x);
        var dist = height / (2 * Math.tan(camera.fov * Math.PI / 360));
        var pos = scene.position;
        var boundingSphere = boxFrmScene.getBoundingSphere();
        var center = boundingSphere.center;
        camera.position.set(center.x, center.y, (dist * 1.1));
        camera.lookAt(pos);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

The deadpool object I used is from here : http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/deadpool-42722.html . I don't know if I have been reading the right questions. I would be very glad if someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm not good with 3D maths.

Edit:
I have tried solution given at this:[How to Fit Camera to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614252/how-to-fit-camera-to-object) but it has not solved my issue. In fact its flipping my object upside down. I am trying to position the object to center of the camera.

---

Edit 2: I have partially fixed this. Now the object is within the camera frustum and fully visible. Now I need to find a way to center it. I changed the whole code below `scene.add(object);`

```
var pos = scene.position;
camera.position.set(pos.x, pos.y, 100);
camera.lookAt(pos);
var boxFrmScene = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(scene);
var height = Math.max(boxFrmScene.size().y, boxFrmScene.size().x);
var fov = camera.fov * (Math.PI / 180);
var distance = Math.abs(height / Math.sin(fov / 2));
camera.position.set(pos.x, pos.y, distance + (height / 2));
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Fit Camera to Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614252/how-to-fit-camera-to-object)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this code after creating mesh,

```
var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh);
box.center(mesh.position);
mesh.localToWorld(box);
mesh.position.multiplyScalar(-1);
```

This will bring your object to the center of the screen