# Scale or zoom object to the size of Viewport

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a VR-World. You can turn and tilt the camera in the center of the world, but you can not move the camera around.

In the VR-World you can attach a Video to the background and play it by clicking on it or moving the crosshair over the element.

The video itself has a "normal" state. Like so:
[Example normal](https://www.directupload.net/file/d/5605/xbfj4y29_png.htm)

And a "zoomed" state. Like so:
[Example zoom](https://www.directupload.net/file/d/5605/it6juf62_png.htm)

In the zoomed state the video should not be larger than the current viewport. I do have the width and height of the video. How can I calculate the correct size of the video (or depth) to fit the size of the viewport?

I could scale the object on its current position, or I could move the object closer to the camera. I'm open for both options.

I have tried the option mentioned here:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589915/three-js-calculate-object-distance-required-to-fill-screen)

```
let vFOV = this._engine.getCurrentCamera().fov * Math.PI / 180;
let ratio = 2 * Math.tan( vFOV / 2 );
let screen = ratio * (window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight);
let size = this._contentMesh.geometry.boundingBox.max.y;

return (size/screen) / 4;
```

The result of the example above is way to close at the camera. Do I overlook something?

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let vFOV = this._engine.getCurrentCamera().fov * Math.PI / 180;
let ratio = 2 * Math.tan( vFOV / 2 );
let size = this._contentMesh.geometry.boundingBox.max.y * 2;
return size / ratio;
```

If you want to set the correct Z position of the object to fit the screen: That's the answer. You can leave out width and height of the Viewport, because it doesn't matter in the calculation.