three.js rendering spheres in wrong position
I am new to three.js and I was trying this code but I encountered unexpected output so wanted to check what I am doing wrong here or looking to find reason behind output i am seeing.
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js'

const scene = new THREE.Scene()

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000)
camera.position.set(75,20,0)


const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
controls.target.set(0, 20, 0)
controls.update()

const sphere1 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(2, 20, 20), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFFFF00}))
sphere1.position.set(-20, 20, 0);
sphere1.castShadow = true
scene.add(sphere1)


const sphere2 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(2, 20, 20), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFFFF00}))
sphere2.position.set(20, 20, 0);
sphere2.castShadow = true
scene.add(sphere2)

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  renderer.render(scene, camera)

}

animate()

I am seeing three issue in this code which I am not able to explain:

I was expecting two sphere appear right and left to each other but here they are appearing front and back
When I change sphere position from (0, 20, 100) sphere moves to left which I dont understand why and another thing is that sphere appears oval and distored in shape, which I dont understand why.


Think about where you have placed your camera.  Typically the camera will be centered in X and Y but with a larger Z.

@TimRoberts thank you so much, now i see !! I am curious why sphere is distorted with position is set with z = 100

Could be perspective and aspect ratio.  If you're looking from an angle, it's not going to be completely spherical.

You set the camera's position to (75,20,0), then target it to (0,20,0). This results in your camera being very far in the X axis, while looking back to the origin (0,0,0) plus 20 units up. You place 2 spheres at (-20,20,0) and (20,20,0), which places them next to eachother on the X axis. The reason they appear like they are front and back is because you are looking at the spheres from the side.
If you want to view the spheres next to eachother, place your camera at (0,20,75).

thank you so much, I am curious why sphere is distorted with position is set with z = 100

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655930/90-degree-field-of-view-without-distortion-in-three-perspectivecamera
