# How can I draw a scale meter?

Tags: three.js

I want to draw (on the renderer) a fixed vertical line (or a bar) that gives info about size/distance or zooming factor like the one in Google Maps (see the [image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18236667/Schermata%20del%202014-11-03%2018%3A19%3A56.png)) (supposing to use a Orbit Control or a Trackball Control). Is it possibile?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350875/three-js-width-of-view/13351534?s=8|2.0266#13351534

Answer (score 0):

why yes, good sir! You could find out the distance quite easily if you have `THREE.OrbitControls` object and a `THREE.Camera`:

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(...);
var camera = ....;
//get distance from camera to 'target' of OrbitControls
var distance = camera.position.distanceTo(controls.target);
```

luckily for us, `THREE.OrbitControls` also has `minDistance` and `maxDistance` attributes which control how close and how far away the camera can move from the target point. So, to get relative position of our camera between `minDistance` and `maxDistance` we can use the following code:

```
var normalizedDistance = (distance- controls.minDistnace) / (controls.maxDistance - controls.minDistance);
```

Now our new `normalizedDistance` variable will store a value between 0 and 1 relative to how far we are from the target, if we are at the `minDistance` - we can't get any closer and `normalizedDistance === 0`, if we are at `maxDistance` and can't get any further, out `normalizedDistance === 1`.

Also, be careful, by default `THREE.OrbitControls.maxDistance` is set to infinity, so to get a meaningful `normalizedDistance` you would have to set `maxDistance` to some reasonable non-infinite value, like say 100 or 1000.