# Three.js - Good z distance of camera for full view of box

Tags: javascript, three.js, perspectivecamera

I display with Three.js a scene of size 700x700. In this scene, I generate a system of particles with random positions between -250 and 250 (for x,y,z), so the box is 500x500 size.

to compute the right distance of camera (for an adapted full view of the box), I tried :

```
    <script>

if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

var container, stats;
var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
var cross;
var width = 700, height = 700;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, width / height, 1, 1000 );
  // tan(pi/6) = 1/sqrt(3) = height/2 / distance_z
  camera.position.z = 250*Math.sqrt(3);

      ...

 for(var p = 0; p < particleCount; p++) {

    // create a particle with random
    // position values, -250 -> 250

    var pX = 250 - Math.random() * 500;
    var pY = 250 - Math.random() * 500;
    var pZ = 250 - Math.random() * 500;

    var particle = new THREE.Vector3(pX, pY, pZ);

    // add it to the geometry
    geometry.vertices.push(particle);

  }

function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = width /height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize( width, height );

  controls.handleResize();

}

...
</script>
```

As you can see, I applied this formula for field of view (FOV)

```
tan(FOV/2) == height/2 / distance_z
```

which gives here : `distance_z = 250 * sqrt(3)`

but when I load the page, the zoom seems to be too high, in a way that I am too near from the 500x500 box.

Why this calculation is not correct in my case ? and How can I have a full view exactly adapted to the size of my 500x500 box ?

Maybe I do a confusion between the size of the scene and the size of my box

Thanks

Comment: I use `6 * geometry.boundingSphere.radius` as the distance. Of course, if your camera position x and z are not 0 then this value will be too high for z. This is a assuming one geometry (your "box"). So this code won't work directly for you, because you'll find need to find the bounding sphere of your box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to compute the camera position so you get a full view of a box.

As explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350875/three-js-width-of-view/13351534#13351534), you can calculate the visible height given the distance from the camera like so:

```
var vFOV = camera.fov * Math.PI / 180;        // convert vertical fov to radians

var height = 2 * Math.tan( vFOV / 2 ) * dist; // visible height
```

What is important is the visibility of the *front face* of the cube.

In your case, the front face has height 500, and since the cube is centered at the origin, the front face of the cube is located at a distance of 250 in front of the origin. So, rewriting the formula above,

```
var dist = 500 / ( 2 * Math.tan( camera.fov * Math.PI / 360 ) );
```

Since the camera must be set back from the *front face*,

```
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 250 + dist );
```

This is the exact solution to make the cube "fit" in the visible height. From there, you can adjust the camera position to your liking. Alternatively, you could ensure a margin by using a slightly larger value for `height` in the formula above.

three.js r.71

Comment: thanks, indeed, I didn't take account of the distance that I have to add (250) to be in front of the front face

Comment: Hands up if you arrived here because you forgot `Math.tan()` takes it's argument in radians. ✋