# How to stick object inside fov

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to figure out how to position an object inside the edge of the camera's fov if it goes outside of it.
I've looked at this: [Three.js - Width of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350875/three-js-width-of-view?lq=1)
But if I plug in the values, it returns 5.12 if the screen width is 512, and 3.12 for height if the screen height is 320.
I have the camera positioned -150 on the z axis, and the objects are located at 0 on the z axis.
I was hoping it would tell me how much x and y distance there is visible in the fov where z axis is 0 if camera is looking along the z axis. That way I could position objects if they go outside the limits.
Anyone know how to get this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer. Had to use some trigonometry.

h = tan(fov/2)*dist
dist is the distance to the object from the camera. h is half of the screen space in y axis.
to get x axis multiply by (screenwidth/screenheight)

Comment: I'm using pointer lock controls for a first person shooter. On mouse click, I want to place an object randomly in the 3D world, but always inside the current viewing port (fov). I'm guessing your answer might hold the key to my problem, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it since the distance to the camera isn't known (because the object still has to be created). Any idea?

Comment: I don't know. maybe if you know the current angle of the camera, and the fov, you could pick a random degree between camera angle and half the fov angle, and then project out a random distance?