# Three.js screen to world position calculation based on browser window size

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm confused about converting screen position to world position in three.js.  I've looked at several answers to questions on Stackoverflow but can't make sense of the formulas and/or extract them from raycasting or mouse testing in the examples (neither of which I'm doing).  I simply want to position a plane in world position according to the width of the scene/window.  For example the bottom right corner of the window minus the width and height of the plane so it's on screen and visible.  Something like this:

```
//geometry and material of the plane
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50, 50);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );

//create plane
plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry,  material);

position = new THREE.Vector3();
position.x = ( window.innerWidth / 2 ) - asquare.geometry.parameters.width;
position.y = - ( window.innerHeight / 2 ) - asquare.geometry.parameters.height;
position.z = 0;

plane.position.set( position.x, position.y, position.z );
```

It's in the right direction but too far, I guess it's the difference between the camera and planes z position that is the issue.  If my camera is at z 500 and the plane is at z 0 how do I adjust the x and y accordingly?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350875/three-js-width-of-view/13351534#13351534