# How to set a sprite size always same when I use PerspectiveCamera

Tags: three.js

Now I have a project must set a obj in word always same size. Use PerspectiveCamera.
I do not want use OrthographicCamera

Comment: See if this pattern works for you: `var vec = new THREE.Vector3(); sprite.scale.x = sprite.scale.y = vec.setFromMatrixPosition( sprite.matrixWorld ).sub( camera.position ).length() / defaultDepth;` Update scale whenever sprite or camera move.

Comment: @WestLangley  thansk  I think it is ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to prevent size attenuation with sprites, and you are using a perspective camera, you can set the `sizeAttenuation` property of your material to false:

```
var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( {

    color: 0xffffff,
    map: texture,
    sizeAttenuation: false

} );
```

EDIT: Updated to three.js r.96

Comment: If I have many sprite  can I add to an container. And set the  container scale?

Comment: That will probably not do what you intend.

Comment: Excuse me，How to get sprite real width on the screen

Comment: This is a guess: To get the sprite size in pixels, you first need to calculate the [visible height in world units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350875/three-js-width-of-view/13351534#13351534) and compare that to the sprite size in world units. That will give you a fraction. Multiply that fraction by the drawing size height in pixels.