# How to setup fixed size(screen space) billboards using glsl

Tags: three.js, glsles

I am trying to create billboard using three.js. I tried using THREE.Sprite however size of sprite changes with distance as I am using perspective projection. I tried to create a plane using custom shaderMaterial with custom shader.

Shader code for scaling billboard

```
 vec4 gl_Position = projectionMatrix * (modelViewMatrix * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) + vec4(position.x, position.y, 0.0, 0.0));'
```

same for non scaling billboard, which I am trying implement

```
float distance = length(modelViewMatrix * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)); 
vec4 newPosition = projectionMatrix * (modelViewMatrix * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) + vec4(position.x, position.y, 0.0, 0.0));
gl_Position= newPosition*distance;
```

Unfortunately there is no changes in the output. Its still scaled billboard. Any suggestion that might fix the problem?

Comment: maybe [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42347761/4045502) will be helpful

Comment: Thanks, I wanted object to be even remain unscaled on zooming also. Ideally it should be in the screen space.